# Laravel 5 Mail Queue is Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I am trying to queue emails in Laravel 5.2 but I keep getting empty payloads in the database (As Below)

[image: Empty Payload]

My `config\queue.php`

```
'connections' => [

    ...

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],

    ...
]
```

My code for Queuing:

```
if(Input::get('email-admin')) {
    $admin_pdf = PDF::loadView('emails.reporting.checkin-report', ['content' => $admin_email])->inline();
    Mail::queue('emails.reporting.checkin-email', [], function ($m) use ($admin_pdf, $start) {
        //Admin should have User ID of '1'
        $admin = User::find(1);
        $report_name = $start->format('F') . '-report.pdf';
        $m->attachData($admin_pdf, $report_name);
        $m->to($admin->email, $admin->first_name)->subject('flexxifit ' . $start->format('F') . ' Report');
    });
}
```

I have also tried `Mail::later()` with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, the serializer does not like byte-strings ($admin_pdf in this case).

You can fix it by base64_encoding the byte-string data before queueing it, then decoding it again in the closure like this:

```
$adminPdf = base64_encode($pdfData); //Encoded here
Mail::queue('emails.reporting.admin-report', $emailData, function (Message $m) use ($adminPdf) {
    $m->attachData(base64_decode($adminPdf), $reportName); //Decoded here
    $m->to($adminEmail)->subject('Admin Report');
});
```

Comment: This is a good point, I did not realise this as this was the first email I tried to queue as it produces a batch of emails. I just assumed I had something configured incorrectly. I will attempt you solution and advise if my results

Answer (score 7):

You should **run the listener** in console:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#running-the-queue-listener)

Comment: I have done this but the issue is that the data isn't being inserted into the database i.e. no payload

Comment: @MichaelSmith Have you fixed that? I am also having same issue

Comment: @Jnanaranjan Yes I have, I have made an edit on the approved answer but you can see the working code here: https://pastebin.com/UiK7HVfJ